# Get scheduled events for a specific interval

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a series of events, set by their frequency of occurrence, for example, weekly (like every Tuesday), monthly (every second number), etc.
There is a start date for a sequence of events and an end date can be specified or omitted.

eg:

```
event = Event(
    name='go to the office', 
    startday='13.10.2020', 
    schedule=Schedule(type='weekly', details={'day':'Tuesday'})
)
```

it is just an example interface, which can be adjusted if required by the tool

The task itself is that I need to make a query with a certain start-end time interval and get all the events in the interval.

Therefore, the question is, are there any libraries that solve such problems, or I have to reinvent the wheel?

I have to do it in Django based project, so if Django based solution is more convenient.

Comment: You can use [django-background-task](https://pypi.org/project/django-background-task/)

Comment: @Akash Joshi, it looks like this lib have a functionality like Celery, but I do not need schedule python tasks, I need to save events and query them in the business logic layer of my app.

Comment: Maybe in that case you need to create your own model save the data and fetch the way you want. I am not aware of any library that can help you with this. Maybe anyone else can help you with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution by myself, with **rrule** from [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html)
It can create repeated (recurrence) events and making queries from them with **between()** method.

```
# pip install python-dateutil
from functools import reduce
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import (
    rrule,
    WEEKLY,
    DAILY,
    MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU
)

events = [
    {
        'type': 'task',
        'rule': rrule(
            WEEKLY,
            dtstart=datetime(year=2020, month=10, day=13),
        ),
        'name': 'Clean room'
    },
    {
        'type': 'party',
        'rule': rrule(
            WEEKLY,
            dtstart=datetime(year=2020, month=10, day=13),
            until=datetime(year=2020, month=12, day=13),
            byweekday=(SA, SU), wkst=MO,
        ),
        'name': 'Dance',
        'participants': ['Willy', 'Sue'],
    },
    {
        'type': 'meditation',
        'rule': rrule(
            DAILY,
            interval=2,
            dtstart=datetime(year=2020, month=10, day=13),
            until=datetime(year=2020, month=12, day=13)
        ),
        'name': 'Think out',
        'location': 'outside',
    },
]


def main():
    all_events = timeline(
        events,
        startday=datetime(year=2010, month=1, day=1),
        endday=datetime(year=2020, month=11, day=1)
    )

    print('Timeline\n---')
    for event in all_events:
        print_event(event)


def timeline(events, startday, endday):
    all_events = reduce(
        lambda all_events, event:
            all_events + events_list(event, startday, endday),
        events,
        []
    )

    return sorted(all_events, key=itemgetter('date'))


def events_list(event, startday, endday):

    dates = event['rule'].between(startday, endday, inc=True)
    inner_events = [{'date': date, 'event': event} for date in dates]

    return inner_events


def print_event(event):
    print(
        f'{event["date"]}: {event["event"]["name"]} ({event["event"]["type"]})'
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Timeline
---
2020-10-13 00:00:00: Clean room (task)
2020-10-13 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-15 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-17 00:00:00: Dance (party)
2020-10-17 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-18 00:00:00: Dance (party)
2020-10-19 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-20 00:00:00: Clean room (task)
2020-10-21 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-23 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-24 00:00:00: Dance (party)
2020-10-25 00:00:00: Dance (party)
2020-10-25 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-27 00:00:00: Clean room (task)
2020-10-27 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-29 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-10-31 00:00:00: Dance (party)
2020-10-31 00:00:00: Think out (meditation)
2020-11-01 00:00:00: Dance (party)
```